# Determine user's device using iOS SDK and full Cocoa Touch / Objective-C code

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk, ipod

I have written the following UIDevice category based on different sources. I've upgraded the `platformCode` method so it's less low-level than can be seen.

This works perfectly, but the `platformCode` method is low level. Do you know if this kind of call can be replaced with Cocoa Touch code? Here's the relevant code:

**UIDevice_enhanced.h**

```
@interface UIDevice (Enhanced)

typedef enum {
    kUnknownPlatform = 0,
    kiPhone1G,
    kiPhone3G,
    kiPhone3GS,
    kiPhone4,
    kiPhone4Verizon,
    kiPhone4S,
    kiPodTouch1G,
    kiPodTouch2G,
    kiPodTouch3G,
    kiPodTouch4G,
    kiPad,
    kiPad2Wifi,
    kiPad2GSM,
    kiPad2CMDA,
    kSimulator
} PlatformType;

- (NSString *) platformName;
- (PlatformType) platform;

@end
```

**UIDevice_enhanced.m**

```
#import "UIDevice_enhanced.h"
#include <sys/utsname.h>

@interface UIDevice (Enhanced)
- (NSString *) platformCode;
@end 


@implementation UIDevice (Enhanced)

// Utility method (private)
- (NSString*) platformCode {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString* platform =  [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return platform;
}

// Public method to use
- (NSString*) platformName {
    NSString* platform = [self platformCode];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";

    return platform;
}

// Public method to use
- (PlatformType) platform {
    NSString *platform = [self platformCode];
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return kiPhone1G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return kiPhone3G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return kiPhone3GS;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return kiPhone4;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])    return kiPhone4Verizon;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return kiPhone4S;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return kiPodTouch1G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return kiPodTouch2G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return kiPodTouch3G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return kiPodTouch4G;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return kiPad;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return kiPad2Wifi;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return kiPad2GSM;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return kiPad2CMDA;
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return kSimulator;

    return kUnknownPlatform;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is perfectly valid Objective-C (as all C code), it's also not too low-level (I do recommend using enums rather than strings for finite multiple-choice sets).

Answer (score 2):

This may be considered an "objective-c" way of doing it:

```
// Utility method (private)
- (NSString *)platformCode {
    // This may or not be necessary 
    // Im not sure if you can have a device thats not currentDevice can you?
    // if ([self isEqual:[UIDevice currentDevice]]) {

    NSString* platform =  [[self.systemName copy] autorelease];
    return platform;

    // Could probably shorten to just
    // return [[self.systemName copy] autorelease];

    // or - return [NSString stringWithString:self.systemName];
}
```

This would be obj-c version of `utsname` `machine` (from this line: `NSString* platform =  [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`).

[`utsname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysutsname.h.html):

> The `<sys/utsname.h>` header defines structure utsname, which includes
>   at least the following members:
>
> `char  sysname[]`    name of this implementation of the operating system
>   `char  nodename[]` name of this node within an implementation-dependent
>   communications network
>   `char  release[]`   current release level of
>   this implementation
>   `char  version[]`   current version level of this
>   release
>   `char  machine[]`    name of the hardware type on which the
>   system is running

[`UIDevice` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/UIDevice_Class.pdf#page12):

> `systemName` The name of the operating system running on the device
>   represented by the receiver. (read-only)
>   `@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *system`

---

But, since systemName only returns @"iPhone OS", to get the actual device model number, you have to use c code.  Here's another way to do it:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *)machine {
     size_t size;

    // Set 'oldp' parameter to NULL to get the size of the data
    // returned so we can allocate appropriate amount of space
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); 

    // Allocate the space to store name
    char *name = malloc(size);

    // Get the platform name
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

    // Place name into a string
    NSString *machine = [NSString stringWithCString:name];

    // Done with this
    free(name);

    return machine;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is objective-C, but that does not allow to differentiate the devices...

Comment: I thought you were asking how to convert the c code for the `platformCode` method to objective-c?  Was there something else you were asking about?

Comment: No, that was exactly what I was asking for, but your code does not return the same values than the C call, it's really less poor. In fact, as far as I have seen, it neither return anything that can be used to achieve the same goal than the C call.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what your asking.  But the answer to that is that you have to use c.  There is no objC way to get the model number.

Comment: Updated link for UIDevice class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the low level C call to get the infoString. For my purposes I've written a tiny Objective-C library that abstracts this away and presents an Objective-C interface.

```
NSLog(@"Big model number: %d", deviceDetails.bigModel);
//Big model number: 4

NSLog(@"Small model number: %d", deviceDetails.smallModel);
//Small model number: 1

if (deviceDetails.model == GBDeviceModeliPhone4S) {
    NSLog(@"It's a 4S");
}
//It's a 4S

if (deviceDetails.family != GBDeviceFamilyiPad) {
    NSLog(@"It's not an iPad");
}
//It's not an iPad

NSLog(@"systemInfo string: %@", [GBDeviceInfo rawSystemInfoString]);
//systemInfo string: iPhone4,1
```

You can get it on github if you like: [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo)